# How to handle OrientationChanged event with vb.net for Windows 8.1 store application

Tags: vb.net, windows-8.1

I installed Windows 8.1 and Visual Studio 2013 RC.

I have created a new Windows Store Project targeting .NET Framework 4.5.1

Then I placed a TextBox on the MainPage.xaml from the Toolbox.

From Properties I changed its name to "TextBox1"

I've read [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.display.displayinformation.orientationchanged), and I imported the classes:

```
Windows.Graphics.Display
Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayInformation
```

then I placed inside the MainPage Class the declation:

```
Private Event OrientationChanged As TypedEventHandler(Of DisplayInformation, Object)
```

and the declaration of a private method:

```
Private Sub ChangeText() Handles Me.OrientationChanged

    TextBox1.Text = "Hello World"
End Sub
```

I checked the Simulator Tab and ran the project.

Then using the Simulator I press the "Rotate clockwise" button,
but the text of TextBox1 does not change.

What's wrong with the code above? Am I missing the whole point of handling events or something else is wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

OrientationChanged does not fire in the simulator.